# why is destructor called earlier?

Tags: c++

I wrote this code to learn the shared_ptr object creation inside my own class.
Why is A object shared_ptr destroyed even before A's print (obj->print() inside B's print) is called?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class A {
    private: string str; 
    public:   
    A(string s){
        str = s;
        cout<<"class A: "<< str << endl;}
    ~A() { cout << "destroying A: " << str << endl;}
    void print() { cout << "A print called"  << endl;}
};

class B {
    private: shared_ptr<A> obj;
    public:
    B() { cout << "default construct called" << endl;}
    B(string s) {
        cout << "shared_ptr creation" <<endl;
        shared_ptr<A> obj = make_shared<A>(s);
        cout << "shared_ptr creation done" <<endl;
    }
    ~B() { cout<<"destroying B" << endl;}
    void print() { obj->print();cout << "B print called" << endl;}
    
};

void func( B i) { i.print();}

int main()
{   
    { 
    B b("hello world");
    func(b);
    }
    cout << "in main"  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**
shared_ptr creation
class A: hello world
shared_ptr creation done
destroying A: hello world
A print called
B print called
destroying B
destroying B
in main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `B::B(string)`, `shared_ptr<A> obj = make_shared<A>(s);` is constructing a local object which gets destroyed immediately when the constructor ends; it has nothing to do with the data member `obj`, which points to nothing as the result.

I think you want:

```
B(string s) {
    cout << "shared_ptr creation" <<endl;
    obj = make_shared<A>(s); // assignment to the data member obj
    cout << "shared_ptr creation done" <<endl;
}
```

Or initialize it in member initializer list.

```
B(string s) : obj(make_shared<A>(s)) { // initialize the data member obj
    cout << "shared_ptr creation done" <<endl;
}
```